# Git version that starts checking SSH key permissions

Tags: git, ssh, permissions

What version of git starts failing on SSH permissions that are too loose?

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't check what the permissions of SSH keys and directories are, OpenSSH does.  Using any version of Git with an OpenSSH version that does this will act the same.

In general, it's just easier to correct the permissions rather than try to work around this, so that's recommended in this case.  If your question is just idle curiosity, it appears from the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) that the key permissions came in with OpenSSH 5.6 and the config permissions came in with OpenSSH 3.9.  In other words, all reasonably modern OpenSSH versions check for this and you'll need to set the permissions appropriately on at least some files if you'd like to use a secure version of OpenSSH.